# Розділові знаки в реченні «як А, Б, а як В — Г»

Tags: пунктуація

Наприклад:

> Як письменники[?] вони схожі[?] а як люди[?] зовсім різні.
>
> Вона поважала Зеника[?] як тямущого спеціаліста[?] але як людину[?] терпіти не могла.
>
> Як товарищ[?] він бажав простити Дмитру цю помилку[?] але й як його менеджер[?] не міг цього собі дозволити.

З одного боку, оце «як щось» тягне виділити комами. З іншого — правопис у [§ 118.а.12.прим3](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par118Ap12prym3) каже: «*Звороти, що вводяться в речення за допомогою сполучника „як“ і мають значення „у ролі кого, чого“, комою не виділяються: „Про масштаби Довженка як письменника можна судити з його найбільшої літературної праці — ‹Зачарованої Десни›“ (Новиченко), „Розглядаємо вашу відповідь як згоду“*». **Чи треба тут ставити кому, чи не треба, чи можна обома способами** (іншими словами: чи підпадає це під значення «у ролі кого, чого», чи ні, чи можна трактувати обома способами)**?**

Також виникає питання щодо знаку посередині другої частини (незалежно від того, чи треба оці «як щось» виділяти комами в загальному випадку). У реченнях на зразок «одне по-одному, а інше [—] по-іншому» часто в другій частині ставиться тире незалежно від наявності тире в першій частині; тож чи дозволено/обов'язково/заборонено ставити тире після другого «як щось» (і якщо там уже є кома, чи витісняє тире кому)? Хоча, мабуть, на це підпитання відповідь я вже знайшов сам — у другій частині таких речень тире зазвичай ставиться через пропущені члени ([§ 121.4](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par121p4)): і якщо щось пропущено (як у прикладах: «[вони] зовсім інші», «[вона його] терпіти не могла», «[він] не міг…»), то тире варто ставити, а якщо нічого не пропущено (наприклад, якщо явно повставляти «вони», «вона», «він»), то тире варто не ставити.

Comment: Я, врешті, здається, вирішив питання сам, але ліньки писати. Якщо комусь треба, я напишу.

Answer (score 2):

Знайшов інформацію на сайті [Онлайн Корректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC/), де також пише, що:

> Кома не ставиться перед зворотами, що вводяться в речення за допомогою
>   сполучника як і мають значення «у ролі кого, чого»

А також на сайті [Вебен](http://webpen.com.ua/pages/Syntax_and_punctuation/comparative_turnover.html) знайшов таку інформацію:

> Коли прикладка з як не має значення причини, то комою не
>   відокремлюється:
>
> **Як листопадне дерево або кущ родини розових** груша поширена в гірських районах Євразії та Північної Африки.
>
> **Шевченко як поет** відомий у всьому світі (можна сказати: Шевченко-поет...).

Гадаю, що речення про які ви запитуєте мають виглядати так:

> Як письменники вони схожі, а (**Між однорідними членами речення,
>   поєднаними протиставними сполучниками а, але, однак, проте, зате, та
>   (=але), так, хоч (хоча) ставимо [кому](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/129.html)**) як люди - зовсім інші.
>
> Вона поважала Зеника як тямущого спеціаліста, але як людину - терпіти
>   не могла.
>
> Як товарищ він бажав простити Дмитру цю помилку, але й як його
>   менеджер не міг цього собі дозволити.